# How can the x-tools C++ crosscompiler build code, which does not use the Pi's FPU?

Tags: c++, hard-float

After starting over with the `x-tools` C++ crosscompiler to build my Raspi apps, I found out that the app runs considerably (approx. 1/3) slower than when built with the `g++` (version 6.5.0) on the Raspi. Running `g++ -Q --help=target` made me suppose that the crosscompiler (version 8.3.0) omits the FPU on the Raspi:

`g++` on the Raspi:

```
-mfloat-abi=                          hard
-mfp16-format=                        none
-mfpu=                                vfp
```

Crosscompiler on my Ryzen workstation:

```
-mfloat-abi=                          soft
-mfp16-format=                        none
-mfpu=                                auto
```

Does that mean that floating-point numer ops are soft-coded in the machine code from the crosscompiler despite the fact that the Raspi does feature an FPU?

**UPDATE:** After following the [ARM hard float doc](https://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort/VfpComparison), I tried these tags both in the compiler, and the linker:

```
-mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp
```

Now the genuine g++ on the Pi refused to compile. The crosscompiler did work, but I can't see any differences compared to the previous config (without the FPU and ABI flags). `-mfloat-abi=softfp` did not work, though.

Comment: Yea, very much looks like it. You might need to explicitly enable use of the hardware fpu.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort/#GCC_floating-point_options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the options of `ct-ng menuconfig` for a second time, I found out what had prevented the crosscompiler from building hard-float code: a **missing FPU option!** There are two options (one for the PF / SIMD unit) and one for hard-float vs. soft-float. Both must be activated manually:

[image: Target options]

The new compiler's name is: `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-g++`

After building the toolchain with both options set as displayed in the screenshot, everything compiles and links well, and the machine code runs at "native" speed.

Answer (score 3):

Note that building soft float SW for Pi OS is not just a missed optimization opportunity, it's a mistake: system libraries are built with hard float ABI and expect float variables in FPU registers. You are apparently not using any such libraries, otherwise your SW would likely crash when you run it on a Pi.

Comment: This puzzles me even more as I copied the necessary libs (there were > 40 of them, including GeographicLib, which definitely uses hard floats) from the Pi into my x-tools environment, so if they required hard floats, my app wouldn't even compile with the crosscompiler, right?

Comment: @Neppomuk It would compile. The crash happens at runtime, when you call a function with an argument in the FPU register, and the function expects it to be on the stack.

Comment: In fact, it did even run without crashing, but at a snail's speed. Supposedly I do have soft-float versions of the necessary libs on my Pi, but relying on soft-float is simply counterproductive.

Comment: @Neppomuk Not many libs use floats in the first place, OpenGL/GLM, GSL, LAPACK/LINPACK and BLAS come to mind.

Comment: GeographicLib not?